# MVC 4 EF multilanguage site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, translation

I have a mvc4 application with a classlibrary with classes.
I have a class accommodation and a class accommodationTranslation wich holds the translations
properties: accommodationId, LanguageId, Name, Description.

So dependent on the languageId I want to load only the translations for the choosen language.

Can anyone give me a hint or example.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you need save which language user choose in a cookie or the user profile and according to its value you call accommodation inner join accommodationTranslation